# Is there a way to determine whether the process was started for the first time or restarted by nodemon due to changes?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I want to run a particular function only when I start the process (eg. by running `nodemon app.js`) for the first time, and ignore it whenever nodemon restarts my script after saving the changes. I had a look at [using events](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/wiki/Events#using-nodemon-events)  with nodemon, but that does not give the desired result. Is it already possible with nodemon or I'll have to make a feature request?

Comment: You could do it using NPM scripts: `"prething": "this runs once"` and `"thing": "nodemon app.js"`, then `npm run thing`.

Comment: I thought of that, but wouldn't that mean `nodemon app.js` will not run as the primary process? Plus, are you suggesting that I run `npm run prething` and `npm run thing` as two different commands?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "primary process". And no, you just run `npm run thing` and NPM calls `prething` (and `postthing` if defined) for you at the appropriate moments.

Comment: That's a neat trick...

Answer (score 0):

The temporary trick that worked "cross-platform" for me was this:

in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "preWHATEVER": "node -e \"const fs=require('fs'); fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/pre_firstrun_flag','')\"",
    "WHATEVER": "nodemon your/app.js"
}, 
...
```

in `app.js`:

```
const isFirstRun = fs.existsSync(__dirname + '/../pre_firstrun_flag','');
if (isFirstRun) {
    fs.unlinkSync(__dirname + '/../pre_firstrun_flag');
    ... your other codes ...
}
```